How do I fix a MODULE_NOT_FOUND error for a module that I don't manually import?
I was just trying to install a shadcn package and was met with this extremely strange error:
 ERR_PNPM_RECURSIVE_EXEC_FIRST_FAIL  Command "cache" not found
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275
  const err = new Error(`Cannot find module '${request}'`);
              ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/XXX/Library/Caches/pnpm/dlx/hx67qbkz3shxeflxwe2je2aqw4/193af67f081-15278/node_modules/.pnpm/@babel+generator@7.26.3/node_modules/@jridgewell/gen-mapping/dist/gen-mapping.umd.js'
    at createEsmNotFoundErr (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:15)
    at finalizeEsmResolution (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1264:15)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:638:14)
    at Function._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:737:31)
    at Function._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1225:27)
    at Function._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1064:27)
    at TracingChannel.traceSync (node:diagnostics_channel:322:14)
    at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:218:24)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1325:12)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:136:16) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: '/Users/XXX/Library/Caches/pnpm/dlx/hx67qbkz3shxeflxwe2je2aqw4/193af67f081-15278/node_modules/.pnpm/@babel+generator@7.26.3/node_modules/@jridgewell/gen-mapping'
}

Node.js v23.3.0

For reference, this was the command I tried to run that caused this error:
pnpm dlx shadcn@latest add accordion

I tried to run these commands to remedy this:
pnpm store prune
rm -rf node_modules pnpm-lock.yaml
pnpm install

I also tried to manually add the package that the error made reference to, I tried to both add it as a dev-dependency, and as a regular package, with:
pnpm add @jridgewell/gen-mapping
pnpm add -D @jridgewell/gen-mapping

Nothing I tried seemed to do the trick, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

fixed it by downgrading manually using
npm i  @jridgewell/gen-mapping@0.3.4 --force

As if you did know I was upgrading my repo just today. Thank you kindest gentleman

i was in the same boat my friend it drove me crazy :D

The problem is caused by the build failure of the newly published version 0.3.6.snapshot
You can force install the last version for fix it by command npm i -f @jridgewell/gen-mapping@0.3.5.

This issue doesn't seem to be related ot shadcn-ui. I think the npm package @jridgewell/gen-mapping broke something.
First delete your package-lock.json and your node_modules folder. Then install version 0.3.4 of the package and afterwards just do an npm install again.
npm i @jridgewell/gen-mapping@0.3.4 --force
Should be working then, for me it fixed the problem!

The package management tool I use is yarn, and I configured resolutions in package.json to solve the problem,
"resolutions": {
    "@jridgewell/gen-mapping": "0.3.3"
  }


The issue appears to be recent. I'm having the same issue as of a few hours ago from this post.
A bug report has already been submitted to the shadcn/ui github repository:
https://github.com/shadcn-ui/ui/issues/6026

Other responses mentioned the @jridgewell/gen-mapping 0.3.6 is buggy. You can exclude to install this specific version with this configuration in your package.json
    "overrides": {
        "@jridgewell/gen-mapping": "<0.3.6 || >0.3.6"
    },

This approach ensures that version 0.3.6 is excluded while allowing future updates to be installed.

Please refer to https://github.com/jridgewell/gen-mapping/issues/14 for this issue
"overrides": {
   "@jridgewell/gen-mapping": "0.3.5"
}


Please share a generic reason as to why certain error comes and how to resolve it. For e.g. in this scenario, the package which is throwing this error mught be broken and the developers need to fix its dependencies.

One way is to just :

unpublished the broken version. Please rerun your package manager to pick up the previous v0.3.5

https://github.com/jridgewell/gen-mapping/issues/14#issuecomment-2530760200
